# start multiple processes with start timer in activiti

Tags: java, timer, jbpm, activiti

How can I start the same process multiple times with 1 start timer event. The process needs to be started every second (asynchronously).

I tried to do this in different ways but the timer waits till the process ends before starting a new process.

I set the timer asynchronously (didn't work).
I set my first service task asynchonously (didn't work)

please any advice? Thank you

I tried this on my servicetask called by my timer that executes another process (async)

```
ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();
    processEngine.getProcessEngineConfiguration().setAsyncExecutorActivate(true);
    processEngine.getProcessEngineConfiguration().setAsyncExecutorEnabled(true);
    AsyncExecutor asyncExecutor =   processEngine.getProcessEngineConfiguration().getAsyncExecutor();
    asyncExecutor.setDefaultAsyncJobAcquireWaitTimeInMillis(1000);
    processEngine.getProcessEngineConfiguration().setAsyncExecutor(asyncExecutor);
     RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();
    runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("TTSProcess", sqsMessage);
```

Comment: can you share a code snippet ?

Answer (score 2):

have you change the process engine configuration for increased the polling time ? Beacause by default activiti check the base every 8 secondes with two requests. So if you want to start workflow each secondes  you need first to change this polling time.

Comment: I see indeed 2 requests every 8 seconds.. I had no explanation for this behaviour. I will try to change the process engine configuration

Comment: To do this you need to change de _ProcessEngineConfiguration_ _JobExecutor_ (or _AsyncJobExecutor_) based on _DefaultJobExecutor_ ( or _DefaultAsyncJobExecutor_) and change the property _waitTimeInMillis_ to 1000 in the activiti.cfg.xml. You can inject the jobExecutor as a bean in the ProcessEngineConfiguration.

Comment: Is this also ok?
AsyncExecutor asyncExecutor =  processEngine.getProcessEngineConfiguration().getAsyncExecutor();
        asyncExecutor.setDefaultAsyncJobAcquireWaitTimeInMillis(waitTimeInMillis)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
Timer updateTimer; //global
updateTimer = new Timer (); //in Constructor/onCreate

//in Method 
updateTimer.schedule( new TimerTask() { 
    public void run(){
        // your code here
    }
},0,1000); //1000 is your 1 second delay
```

Hope this helps. If there are mistakes, please correct me, I just wrote this on my Smartphone and wasn't able to compile.